# How to execute code when a Python script is closed out?

Tags: python

I have a raspberry pi that records temperature and stores them in a MySQL database on my website. I often toy with the script, so I am hitting `ctrl+c` on the running script and re executing it. I would like to properly issue `close()` on the database connection. How can I run a line of code when the script is exited in python?

```
import MySQLdb
con = MySQLdb.connect(...)
cursor = con.cursor() 

# ...

#if script closes:
   #con.close()
```

Answer (score 6):

```
import MySQLdb
con = MySQLdb.connect(...)
cursor = con.cursor() 

try:
    # do stuff with your DB    
finally:
    con.close()
```

The `finally` clause is executed on success as well as on error (exception).

If you hit Ctrl-C, you get a `KeyboardInterrupt` exception.

Answer (score 0):

or:

```
import atexit

def close_db(con):
    con.close()
    # any other stuff you need to run on exiting

import MySQLdb
con = MySQLdb.connect(...)

# ...

atexit.register(close_db, con=con)
```

See [here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/atexit.html) for more info.